# PHP simple mail function is not working

Tags: php

I have got this simple php mail function

```
$to = "munucom@mail.ru";
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "Hello world!";
$headers = "From: munucom@mail.ru" . "\r\n" .
"CC: munucom@mail.ru";
if(mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers)){
  echo "done";  
}
```

It echos done but when i check my email there is nothing.Even in spam section

Comment: Is this on a localhost or on a hosted server?

Comment: mail function not worked in localhost

Comment: Have you installed a mailingserver?

Comment: Never heard of it @Qirel

Comment: @lIPTT are you using XAMPP?

Comment: @lIPTT have you checked your c:\xampp\mailoutput folder?

Answer (score 0):

Use PHPMailer library.It is better than use mail native function because in PHPMailer you can use user authentication to avoid to send the email to spam.You can use this library without to configure a mail server.It's more easiest to debug. You can download in this link https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

See an example:

```
$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                           // 1 = errors and messages
                                           // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                 
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 587;                   // SMTP port
$mail->Username   = "yourusername@gmail.com";  // username
$mail->Password   = "yourpassword";            // password

$mail->SetFrom('user@gmail.com', 'Test');

$mail->Subject    = "I hope this works!";

$mail->MsgHTML('Blah');

$address = "test@test.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "Test");

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Comment: I have tried using this.but it just takes too long for it to load

Comment: This could the speed of your local connection with the server host.PHPMailer is one of php mail library used  in most applications.

Comment: With PHPMailer you dont need configure a local mail server;

Comment: I am trying to use it now but it takes 3-4 minutes just to refresh page